# Double sorting a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort my dataframe alphabetically by state (it is technically out of order as of now), and then try sorting the IncomeID column by 1-6 for every six rows. It should follow the pattern 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on for the entire dataset. Take note of rows 7-12, whose order is incorrect. I know how to sort the states alphabetically, but I am unsure of the second part, or if it is even a possibility. I have included a picture of the relevant columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Snip of df]

Comment: Did you read [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns) ?

Comment: @markus I think the question is more than that

Comment: @markus - Yes, however, my situation was a bit different than that one unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `arrange`, where we create a grouping index with `gl` for every 6 rows, and use that in the `arrange` along with 'IncomeID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     arrange(LocationDesc, as.integer(gl(n(), 6, n())), IncomeID)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question today and yesterday. It was exactly what I was looking for - you are truly an R professional!

Comment: @autechre i think the dupe target is not correct.